# Modifying gethostbyname (res_search) source code - Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: linux, gethostbyname

I am trying to modify the behaviour of the DNS lookup functions in Linux for my project by setting it to write a random string in a file as a test.

Linux use some DNS resolver functions, mainly **gethostbyname**. Looking forward, I found out that the resolver functions are within the *glibc6* library. So, I downloaded it, compiled, generating the *libresolv.so*, *libnss_dns.so* dynamic libraries. Then, I replaced the existing ones on my system, at */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*.

Note: I found out these libraries are the ones that resolves queries by modifying **gethostbyname** code and compiling again. Then, I saw which dynamic libraries changed.

By creating a program that uses **res_query** directly (a resolver function) and compiling with *-lresolv*, it works (I used *ldd* command and it uses the resolver library I created). But, using **gethostbyname** directly from the code, using *wget* or browsing the web I can't get it right.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered what should I do:

Firstly, the function called isn't **gethostbyname**. It is **_nss_dns_gethostbyname3_r**, defined in *resolv/nss_dns/dns-host.c*. Looking at the source I realized that this function called another one to resolve DNS names, **__libc_res_nsearch**, defined in *resolv/res-query.c*. So this is the function! I added some file writting commands there and it worked like a charm. I called it from C code using **gethostbyname**, used *wget* and Firefox, all worked. When you compile the code you should replace the libresolv.so of your system by the new one.

Note: my glibc version is 2.19.

I hope this helps someone.